# Set value to another form

Tags: c#

I have to form `Form1` and `Form2`

`Form1` source

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.SetBtn = "teste test";
            frm.Show();
        }

        public string setLb
        {
            set
            {
                label1.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Form2` source

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.setLb = "test test";
        }

        public string SetBtn
        {
            set
            {
                button1.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to set text of label in `Form1` and text of button on `Form2`
I use same method to set value but only work when set value from `Form1` to `Form2`. Button1.Text on `Form2` changed to `teste test` but nothing happend on `Form1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to your `Form1` instance to the `Form2` instance.

You can do that like this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2(this); // <---- Pass a reference to this form to Form2
            frm.SetBtn = "teste test";
            frm.Show();
        }

        public string setLb
        {
            set
            {
                label1.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you would need to change the `Form2` implementation a little aswell:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Form1 other;

        //Empty constructor for the designer
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Form2(Form1 other)
        {
            this.other = other;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            other.setLb = "test test";
        }

        public string SetBtn
        {
            set
            {
                button1.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Constructor method  , here is example

In form2

```
public Form2(string strTextBox)
{
 InitializeComponent(); 
 label1.Text=strTextBox;
}
```

In form1 click event

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Form2 frm=new Form2(textBox1.Text);
frm.Show();
}
```

For more information , reference [Passing Data Between Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms) !

Answer (score 0):

In Form2 you have to add a parameter for the Form1.

i.e.

```
// Form1
...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
    frm.SetBtn = "teste test";
    frm.Show();
}
...

// Form2
public Form2(Form frm1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    frm1.setLb = "test test";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1() {
InitializeComponent();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
frm.Show();
}
}
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
Form _frm;
public Form2(Form frm)
{
_frm = frm;
InitializeComponent();
}`enter code here`

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form1 formVariable = (Form1)_frm;
formVariable.textBox.Text = "Hello";
}
}
```

Comment: if you want to set value to another form textbox